# Mathematical condition of Stationary Planet

Tags: positional-astronomy

In an old astronomy book I find the following definitions:

$\vec r_1$ *Position vector of Earth (heliocentric)*

$\vec r_2$ *Position vector of a Planet (heliocentric)*

$\vec v_1$ *Velocity vector of Earth (heliocentric)*

$\vec v_2$ *Velocity vector of the Planet (heliocentric)*

$\vec n_1$ *Angular velocity vector of Earth (heliocentric)*

*Then, the geocentric position vector of the planet, and its geocentric velocity vector are:*
$$\vec r=\vec r_2- \vec r_1$$
$$\vec v=\vec v_2- \vec v_1$$
*A planet is said to be stationary when its geocentric longitude does not vary*.

So far, no problem, but now it says:

***The projection on the ecliptic of the relative areal velocity is then zero and, therefore***:
($\times$ is the cross product and $\cdot$ is the dot product)
$$\boldsymbol{\vec n_1 \cdot (\vec r \times \vec v)=0}$$
It is the sentence in bold and the subsequent mathematical expression that I do not understand. Why?

Thank you and best regards.